# In SQL select query, remove first and last 0 values but not in the middle

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Here is my problem statement. I got some data from a sensor in this format:

```
ts                 |i|p  |idx
2019-10-28 06:00:01|0|  0|75522
2019-10-28 06:10:00|0|  0|75522
2019-10-28 06:20:00|0|  0|75522
2019-10-28 06:30:00|0|  0|75522
2019-10-28 06:40:00|0|  0|75522
2019-10-28 06:50:00|0|  0|75522
2019-10-28 07:00:00|0|  0|75522
2019-10-28 07:10:00|0|103|75526
2019-10-28 07:20:00|0|114|75535
2019-10-28 07:30:00|1|141|75550
2019-10-28 07:40:00|1|203|75575
2019-10-28 07:50:00|1|203|75575
2019-10-28 08:00:00|1|203|75575
...
2019-10-28 15:30:00|1|144|79397
2019-10-28 15:40:00|1|127|79414
2019-10-28 15:50:00|0|113|79427
2019-10-28 16:00:00|0|106|79437
2019-10-28 16:10:00|0| 99|79443
2019-10-28 16:20:00|0| 96|79445
2019-10-28 16:30:01|0| 96|79446
2019-10-28 16:40:00|0|  0|79446
2019-10-28 16:50:00|0|  0|79446
2019-10-28 17:00:00|0|  0|79446
2019-10-28 17:10:00|0|  0|79446
```

For a given day, I would like to extract values like this, removing data where idx has not changed BUT only at beginning and end of the day:

```
2019-10-28 07:00:00|0|0|75522   -- Remove all unchanged values before
2019-10-28 07:10:00|0|103|75526
2019-10-28 07:20:00|0|114|75535
2019-10-28 07:30:00|1|141|75550
2019-10-28 07:40:00|1|203|75575 
2019-10-28 07:50:00|1|203|75575 -- Keep this
2019-10-28 08:00:00|1|203|75575 -- Keep this
...
2019-10-28 15:30:00|1|144|79397
2019-10-28 15:40:00|1|127|79414
2019-10-28 15:50:00|0|113|79427
2019-10-28 16:00:00|0|106|79437
2019-10-28 16:10:00|0|99|79443
2019-10-28 16:20:00|0|96|79445
2019-10-28 16:30:01|0|96|79446  -- Remove all unchanged values after
```

I tried to play with LAG to compute the idx delta bewteen row and row -1.

```
SELECT ts, i, p, idx, idx - LAG (idx, 1, idx) OVER (ORDER BY ts) 
FROM my_table 
WHERE DATE(ts) = '2019-10-28'
ORDER BY ts ASC
```

and the result is promising:

```
2019-10-28 06:00:01|0|0|75522|0   -- To be removed 
2019-10-28 06:10:00|0|0|75522|0   -- To be removed 
2019-10-28 06:20:00|0|0|75522|0   -- To be removed 
2019-10-28 06:30:00|0|0|75522|0   -- To be removed 
2019-10-28 06:40:00|0|0|75522|0   -- To be removed 
2019-10-28 06:50:00|0|0|75522|0   -- To be removed 
2019-10-28 07:00:00|0|0|75522|0   -- Keep this
2019-10-28 07:10:00|0|103|75526|4
2019-10-28 07:20:00|0|114|75535|9
2019-10-28 07:30:00|1|141|75550|15
2019-10-28 07:40:00|1|203|75575|15 
2019-10-28 07:50:00|1|203|75575|0 -- Keep this
2019-10-28 08:00:00|1|203|75575|0 -- Keep this
...
2019-10-28 15:30:00|1|144|79397|20
2019-10-28 15:40:00|1|127|79414|17
2019-10-28 15:50:00|0|113|79427|13
2019-10-28 16:00:00|0|106|79437|10
2019-10-28 16:10:00|0|99|79443|6
2019-10-28 16:20:00|0|96|79445|2
2019-10-28 16:30:01|0|96|79446|1
2019-10-28 16:40:00|0|0|79446|0   -- Keep this
2019-10-28 16:50:00|0|0|79446|0   -- To be removed 
2019-10-28 17:00:00|0|0|79446|0   -- To be removed 
2019-10-28 17:10:00|0|0|79446|0   -- To be removed
```

Now, how can I tweak the query to remove all first 0 and all last 0, but keep the last first 0, and first last 0 (you follow me :- !) and do not touch the values in the middle even 0 values?

Is it better to do it through a post treatment in my Python code?

---

Edit 31-Oct-19: The idx column contains a data always increasing, except when the source read is changed. In my case, I take the data from a consumption meter. But the electricity company has decided to change the meter... Now restarting from 0. So it would be better to analyse days from the timestamp + value changes from first/last record of the day!

Comment: Can we assume that the `idx` values monotonically increases?

Comment: do you use mysql or sqlite?

Comment: Hello @RadimBača, thanks for your questions. idx is a timestamp that evolves ~10 minutes, so yes it will always increase. I use a sqlite3 db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this from your initial data:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (
    SELECT T1.*, 
        MIN(TS) OVER (PARTITION BY IDX) AS MIN_TS,
        MAX(TS) OVER (PARTITION BY IDX) AS MAX_TS,
        MIN(TS) OVER () AS MIN_GLOBAL_TS,
        MAX(TS) OVER () AS MAX_GLOBAL_TS
    FROM TABLENAME T1
    ) T2
WHERE ((TS = MIN_TS OR TS = MAX_TS) 
    and TS !=  MIN_GLOBAL_TS 
    and TS !=  MAX_GLOBAL_TS)
    or MIN_TS = MAX_TS
```

Here you find first and last timestamp for any given idx, then select those strings, which timestamp is first or last, while also checking for start and end of the day (global min and max) and removing those values that correspond to them.

I assume that your timestamp is in date format.

*Edited query to return the row if there are no values repeated at the end or start of the day.*

Comment: I like your solution, however, it will not work if you have more days in the data https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9a382d4894569831eb3a4d80414e03e8

Comment: @Radim I agree, but question states "for a given day".

Comment: @Radim Also, did you check your answer on multiple days sample? I checked it and 
I suspect that the string with timestamp '2019-10-29 8:00:00' shouldn't be there. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=74e5a6aa9617066ae694b591c8f2ca43

Comment: I comment on this in my answer. I believe that 8:00:00 should be there since it is the first row of the last `idx` in the day.

Comment: I try to answer to both of you by first saying thank you for your time on this tricky problem (at least for me !). In my database I collect all the data (I have years of data inside) but my query should return the data for a given day passed as argument on my function executing the query. @RadimBača 8:00:00 (AM) is not the last idx in the day (I put '...' to simplify the example). In this particular example, I need to keep all the data between [7:00:00 and 16:40:00].

Comment: Hello @TheNikita I tested you solution... Really ingenious, thanks! One problem I see, if there are no values repeated at the end of the day, this query skip the last record.

Comment: It really does, @Fabrice . I will edit my answer with this problem in mind.

Comment: @Fabrice , It also skipped the first record if there were no repeated values at the start. Edited querry should solve this problems. Here is the link to the test: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=12261353114ef8d9d7fa1d3647b7aefd

Comment: @TheNikita, excellent, just tested on my database and seems working fine. I added "WHERE DATE(TS) = '<my date>'" after "FROM T1" to retrieve the given day. Finally I need also to get the delta between 2 idx. I included a idx - lag(idx,1,idx) over () in the first select statement.

Comment: The only minor issue I encountered is when I'm calculating the idx diff, I need to retrieve  the record of the previous day. A record taken at 00:00 covers the recording from 23:50 the previous day. But it becomes really tricky!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you use MySQL and your `idx` values increase in the time you may use the following SQL

```
SELECT ts, i, p, idx
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        min(ts) OVER (partition by date(ts), idx) min_ts_per_day_idx,
        max(ts) OVER (partition by date(ts), idx) max_ts_per_day_idx,
        min(idx) OVER (partition by date(ts)) min_idx_per_day,
        max(idx) OVER (partition by date(ts)) max_idx_per_day
    FROM tab
) t
WHERE (idx != min_idx_per_day and idx != max_idx_per_day) or
  (idx = min_idx_per_day and ts = max_ts_per_day_idx) or
  (idx = max_idx_per_day and ts = min_ts_per_day_idx)
```

[**DBFIDDLE Example**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=283973db07a98051ca0306556e7b4545)

If you have just one `idx` per day than it is not clear what should be returned. My solution returns the first and the last row in such a case.

Comment: I tested your query on my dataset, but I would avoid to rely on the idx ... A req I have not provided, the meter has been changed and my idx has restarted from 0. Would really prefer to parse values to remove duplicates from beginning of the day until the first non redundant is encountered, the same from end of day.

Answer (score 0):

I would interpret this as:

- Keep all records where the idx value is not zero or the next or previous values are not zero.
- Filter out all other records before or the first non-zero
- Filter out all other records after the last non-zero

Here is one method:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(idx) over (partition by date(ts) order by date ts) as prev_idx,
             lead(idx) over (partition by date(ts) order by date ts) as next_idx,
             min(case when idx <> 0 then ts end) over (partition by date(ts)) as first_ts_not0,
             max(case when idx <> 0 then ts end) over (partition by date(ts)) as last_ts_not0,
      from my_table t
     ) t
where (idx <> 0 or prev_idx <> 0 or next_idx <> 0) or
      (ts >= first_ts_not0 and
       ts <= last_ts_not0
      );
```

Comment: Hello @Gordon, I do not understand your way to proceed. in my DB idx values are not 0 (except when meter is changed, it retarts from 0). I guess you're restarting from my initial proposal.

Comment: @Fabrice . . . Your question says:  "but keep the last first 0, and first last 0 (you follow me :- !)".  The `0` value seems to be a special value according to what you are describing.

Comment: Yes you're right, but this statement is based on the result of my query proposal. Do you elaborate on this ? If yes, I have to consider that 't' in your query is the result of my query above ?

Comment: @Fabrice . . . No, it is just an alias for your table.

Comment: if you consider my original table (the extract at the beginning of my question), there is no 0 in idx column (except if the counting restarts from 0 which has happened one time in 10 years)